# Unable to locate element exception - Java Selenium

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, iframe, webautomation

I'm getting an *Unable to locate element* exception, for reasons beyond me.

Here's the website: https://bo.competentfinman.com:1467/capexweb/capexweb/

And here's my code:

```
package artifactidshilpipackage;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;
import io.github.bonigarcia.wdm.WebDriverManager;

public class shilpi {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        WebDriver driver;
        WebDriverManager.firefoxdriver().setup();
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        driver.get("https://bo.competentfinman.com:1467/capexweb/capexweb/");
        Thread.sleep(3000);
        driver.switchTo().frame("main");
        driver.findElement(By.id("dfuserid")).sendKeys("***");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("dfpassword")).sendKeys("***");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("B1")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[1]/a")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr/td/input")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("topsegment")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Select dropdown = new Select(driver.findElement(By.name("topsegment")));
        dropdown.selectByValue("F&O");
        driver.findElement(By.name("nodeIcon3")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.id("itemTextLink5")).click();
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        driver.findElement(By.name("B1")).click();
        // String a
        // driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/table[2]/tbody/tr[108]/td[2]/b")).getText();
        // int b = Integer.parseInt(a);
    }
}
```

I had the same problem when I tried to use nested frames on someone's recommendation. The nested frame didn't work. But I'm on the correct frame I believe...

Comment: Minor suggestion: can you [edit] the title to be more specific to the question? This would help people who might know the answer (or who are facing a similar problem) find the question more easily.

Comment: Can you edit your question and share the error stack?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below line is incorrect:

```
driver.findElement(By.id("dfuserid")).sendKeys("***");
```

Notice the HTML below. It is the `@name` attribute which we need to use and not `@id`.

[image]

So the code should be:

```
driver.findElement(By.name("dfuserid")).sendKeys("***");
```

Comment: Oh. my.god.  this cannot be. I've looked everywhere. It has been 2 days. I have 3 follicles left on my head!? I even tried xpath?? how is this possible?? I'm so stupid. What do i do? Do i delete this question? Thanks for the answer, please come and bonk me with a baseball bat as well.

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77001025/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.